# High Transmission Power : BPSK or QPSK?

Tags: qpsk, bpsk

In BPSK,
the constellation consists of 2 points (equiprobable) spaced at distance of $\sqrt{E_b}$ each from the origin.

So the average power from the constellation can be obtained by:

- For BPSK, $P = \frac{E_b+E_b}{2} = E_b.$
- For QPSK, 4 points which are equiprobable are spaced at distance of $\sqrt{2E_b}$ from origin each, that is they are placed on vertices of a square of side $2\sqrt{E_b}$. So, for QPSK, $P = \frac{2\cdot4\cdot E_b}{4}=2E_b.$

So, does this mean that the power required for QPSK is more than BPSK when the probability of error is same for both?

Note: $E_b$ is the energy per bit and $P$ is the power which is assumed as proportional to the distance of the signal point from origin in the constellation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since for QPSK each symbol carries two bits, it is not surprising that the average energy *per symbol* must be greater for QPSK than for BPSK to achieve the same error probability. What counts is the *energy per bit* that is necessary to achieve a certain error probability, and this energy per bit is the same for BPSK and QPSK.

Answer (score 1):

That's right. When we compare BPSK and QPSK at *equal energy per bit*, we find that QPSK requires twice the power of BPSK. From [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase-shift_keying):

> Although QPSK can be viewed as a quaternary modulation, it is easier
>   to see it as two independently modulated quadrature carriers. With
>   this interpretation, the even (or odd) bits are used to modulate the
>   in-phase component of the carrier, while the odd (or even) bits are
>   used to modulate the quadrature-phase component of the carrier. BPSK
>   is used on both carriers and they can be independently demodulated.
>
> As a result, the probability of bit-error for QPSK is the same as for
>   BPSK:
>
> $P_b = Q\left(\sqrt{\frac{2E_b}{N_0}}\right).$
>
> However, in order to achieve the same bit-error probability as BPSK, QPSK uses twice the
>   power (since two bits are transmitted simultaneously).